# How to display data in specific conditions using recyclerview in Andriod?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

The code below is the list adapter, I want to display only the data that meet the conditions where "isActive" = true and sort the data by age. 
I tried to check and filter the data on onBindViewHolder, but it only prevents the data from inserting, the list still remains at recycler View.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DeveloperViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem currentItem = DeveloperList.get(position);

        String name = currentItem.getName();
        String phone = currentItem.getPhone();
        String isActive = currentItem.getIsActive();
        holder.check=isActive;


        if(isActive.equals("true")) {
            holder.txtname.setText(name);
            holder.txtphone.setText(phone);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return DeveloperList.size();
    }

    public class DeveloperViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView txtname;
        public TextView txtphone;
        public String check;

        public DeveloperViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.developername1);
            txtphone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.developernumber1);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        ListItem clickItem = DeveloperList.get(pos);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("balance", clickItem.getBalance());
                        intent.putExtra("picture", clickItem.getPicture());
                        intent.putExtra("age", clickItem.getAge());
                        intent.putExtra("name", clickItem.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("gender", clickItem.getGender());
                        intent.putExtra("phone", clickItem.getPhone());
                        intent.putExtra("address", clickItem.getAddress());
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked" + clickItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

Comment: add an else to the condition in onBind() . if(isActive.equals("true")) // set values else set empty

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't give the adapter an unprepared list. You should sort and filter the list before you give it to the adapter.

Otherwise, you will "confuse" the adapter because elements positions will not be correct (ie element 3 is not active so visible element 3 is actually element 4).

Answer (score 0):

Sort the developerList before sending it to adapter class

First, create a `Comparator` class to sort

```
class SortbyAge implements Comparator<ListItem> 
{ 
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of age
    public int compare(ListItem a, ListItem b) 
    { 
        return a.getAge() - b.getAge(); 
    } 
}
```

Then write this code before sending it to the adapter.

```
Collections.sort(developerList , new SortbyAge()); 
ArrayList<ListItem> developers = new ArrayList();
for(ListItem item : developerList) {
 if(item.getIsActive().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
   developers.add(item);
 }
}
```

Now just send the `developers` object to the adapter.